# DataGrid reverts the values back to original when leaving row

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

For some reason, when I updated values in a DataGrid, they are not persisted in the in-memory object? In fact, during editing of cells the new values are displayed, but as soon as I tab onto the next row, the values revert back.

Here's my DataGrid definition:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Position X" Binding="{Binding Position.X, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Position Y" Binding="{Binding Position.Y, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Position Z" Binding="{Binding Position.Z, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rotation" Binding="{Binding Angles[2], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The object is:

```
public class Box{
  public Vector3D Position { get; set; }
  public double[] Angles { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT1**:

Upon further examination, I noticed that `Vector3D` (of `System.Windows.Media.Media3D`) is a struct, not a class. Because of this I suspect that indirection of `Position.X` does not work.

That being said, when I removed all but the "Rotation" binding, which is `double[]`, it still did not work.

**EDIT2**: Diagnostics of the Binding report that the binding is *deactivating* and *detaching*.

Comment: Show Vector3D class / struct

Comment: @Blam, it's a [.NET class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.vector3d.aspx)

Comment: @NewDev, you need to commit the edit

Comment: @Blam, Actually, Vector3D as it turns out, is not a `class`, it's a `struct`... I suspect that it might be the culprit - see updated question

Answer (score 0):

I got managed to bind your `Vector3D` to the `DataGridTextColumn` by creating a value converter:

```
public class StringToStructConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private Vector3D vector3D = new Vector3D();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        vector3D = (Vector3D)value;
        if (parameter.ToString() == "X") return vector3D.X.ToString();
        else if (parameter.ToString() == "Y") return vector3D.Y.ToString();
        else if (parameter.ToString() == "Z") return vector3D.Z.ToString();
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(string) || targetType != typeof(Vector3D)) return false;

        if (parameter.ToString() == "X") vector3D.X = double.Parse(value.ToString());
        else if (parameter.ToString() == "Y") vector3D.Y = double.Parse(value.ToString());
        else if (parameter.ToString() == "Z") vector3D.Z = double.Parse(value.ToString());
        return vector3D;
    }
}

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Items, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=This}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Position X" Binding="{Binding Position, 
Converter={StaticResource StringToStructConverter}, ConverterParameter=X, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Position Y" Binding="{Binding Position, 
Converter={StaticResource StringToStructConverter}, ConverterParameter=Y, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Position Z" Binding="{Binding Position, 
Converter={StaticResource StringToStructConverter}, ConverterParameter=Z, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rotation" Binding="{Binding Angles[2], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

However this method is not perfect and you could save yourself a whole heap of trouble if you change your `Vector3D` struct to a class with the same properties. You could even keep your struct (I'm guessing you have your reasons for choosing that in the first place), but just convert it to a class just to edit it in the `DataGrid` and then convert back afterwards? That could be done in milliseconds, but could save you hours of headache. :)

Comment: yeah, this value converter would not "convert back" correctly.