# Binding when the Property is Vector3D, which is a struct

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, ivalueconverter, imultivalueconverter

I'm trying to bind 3 `TextBox`es (as a first step, but really 3 `DataGrid` columns) to components of a [Vector3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.vector3d.aspx) property. Notice, though, that `Vector3D` is a struct and is thus value-type.

The idea for the binding is to be able to edit a `Vector3D` property, such that each vector component X, Y, Z is individually editable.

The following does not work:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Position.X}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Position.Y}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Position.Z}"/>
```

Is this possible without rewriting my models to wrap a Vector3D struct with a class?

Comment: What happens if you just try it?

Comment: @Clemens, The values revert back to the original and no change is made. Binding traces show something related to deactivating/detaching, which I presume means that the change is made to a copy of the Property, rather than to the original.

Comment: You need commit the edits

Comment: @GarryVass, Your solution didn't work for me in the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796224/datagrid-reverts-the-values-back-to-original-when-leaving-row) I asked.

Comment: Yes, it actually works.  And it's the same answer for this question.  It also looks like you need to fix your binding configuration here.  Along with the INPC implementation.

Comment: @GarryVass, Let me try it again on this simplified version. But can you tell me, why is it that I need to commit the edits explicitly. Is this because of a struct?

Comment: You need to commit edits explicitly because Microsoft says that you will get random/unpredictable results otherwise.

Comment: @GarryVass, in which cases? Can you give a link where they talk about it?

Comment: Best approach.  Get the class working as described and then fill in if there's any missing bits.  You jumped the gun on thinking it didn't work :)